# Only boundary points can be support points?

Tags: real-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm confused by a claim I've read in a textbook--that only boundary points can be support points. Here are the details.

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a topological vector space $X$. A point $x \in A$ is a *support point* of $A$ if there's a nonzero continuous linear functional on $X$ that is minimised over $A$ at $x$.

But according to this definition every point in $A$ is a support point: just consider the nonzero continuous linear function $f=1$. In particular, it's not the case that only boundary points are support points.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: What has this to do with convex analysis???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood linearity. The function $f = 1$ is not linear; it fails both additivity and scalar homogeneity. While a constant function will also minimise any $A$ at all points simultaneously, the only linear constant function is the $0$ functional, which is explicitly excluded.

Note also the other trivial case, where $X = \{0\}$, is included vacuously: there is no non-zero functional on $X = \{0\}$, so $A$ has no support points.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking $f$ is convex instead of linear! Silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @aduh You're welcome!

Comment: Is there a simple way to see that the claim in the book is true? I'm still missing something. I can show that if $x \in A$ minimises $f$ and $f(x)>0$, then $x$ is not an interior point of $A$, but I don't see it when $f(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: I'm curious to see your argument, and why this would be important. Essentially, my hint would be, take $u$ such that $f(u) \neq 0$ (exists, as $f \neq 0$). Indeed, you can assume $f(u) > 0$ for simplicity, by replacing $u$ by $-u$ if necessary. Then, consider the line $x + \lambda u$...

Comment: My argument was: If $x$ is an interior point, then there's some circled neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that's a subset of $A$. Then, for sufficiently small $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $\alpha x \in A$ and $f(\alpha x)<f(x)$ (here assuming $f(x) > 0$), contradicting that $x$ is a minimiser.

Comment: You really want an $\alpha$ sufficiently close to $1$, not sufficiently small. If $f(x) < 0$, then you could take a sufficiently small $\alpha > 1$. It wouldn't work for $f(x) = 0$ though.